# How can I change '01020304' to '01,02,03,04' using SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, split

Given the following SQL, how can I change the value in `@x` from `01020304` to `01,02,03,04`?

```
declare @x varchar(256)

set @x = '01020304'

--
-- How to change '01020304' to '01,02,03,04'?
--
select @x
```

Comment: Will the input always be 8 characters long? Will you ever encounter `010202040506` or `1112131415`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method is a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select convert(varchar(max), '01020304') as rest, convert(varchar(max), '') as new_str, 1 as lev
      union all
      select stuff(rest, 1, 2, '') as rest, concat(new_str, ',', left(rest, 2)), lev + 1
      from cte
      where rest > ''
     )
select top (1) stuff(new_str, 1, 1, '')
from cte
order by lev desc;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=16c08b9eb4959185e9c39ce442112585) is a db<>fiddle.

If the string could have more than 100 elements, you will want to add `option (maxrecursive 0)`.

Comment: I think you opted for this approach for fun :P

Comment: @Dai . . . You are probably correct.  But it seems like a reasonable approach.

Comment: Thank you Gordon.  That works very well.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Is the `CONVERT( varchar(max), '' )` necessary compared to using a `''` literal? I'm curious how SQL Server handles string allocations and string operations in-memory - are they immutable strings (a-la Java and .NET) or are they all expandable strings? And is a `char(8000)` (or `varchar(8000)`) guranteed to be a fixed-sized buffer in-memory? What about `varchar(max)`? AFAICT The technical details of their storage are only documented when they're used for columns, not variables.

Comment: @Dai . . . Yes.  SQL Server is way too finicky about types in recursive CTEs.  Just check for yourself.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Your fiddle is working while query giving error - Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "new_str" of recursive query "cte".
.

Comment: Another good reason to stop using them and use a Tally then, Gordon.

Answer (score 3):

I tend to avoid recursive ctes if possible. For a small set like this it doesn't really make any difference but a recursive cte used to increment is really still an RBAR operation. https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/hidden-rbar-counting-with-recursive-ctes

I prefer to use a tally for this kind of thing. If you have a longer input string you would need to use a larger tally table but that is not a big deal. For this post I just used an inline one.

```
declare @x varchar(256) = '01020304'

declare @result nvarchar(100) = ''
;
with E1(N) as
(
    select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)
),
cteTally(N) AS 
(
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E1
)

select @result = @result + substring(@x, t.N, 1) + case when t.N % 2 = 0 and t.N < len(@x) then ',' else '' end
from cteTally t
where t.N <= len(@x)
order by t.N

select @result
```

Comment: So glad *someone* posted a solution that isn't iterative. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @x varchar(256)
set @x = '01020304'
set @x = replace(@x, '0', ',0')

set @x = substring(@x, 2, len(@x))
select @x
```

Without doubt, I am assuming your input will be more or less same.

Comment: Short and good answer provided.

Comment: This works for the sample data but I highly doubt the real data is so simple which means this likely isn't going to work.

Comment: @SeanLange: Perhaps. I have assumed the input/output based on question.

Answer (score 1):

While @GordonLinoff's answer is probably the most *correct* and general/universal, there are simpler alternatives depending on the constraints on format of `@x`.

For example:

```
DECLARE @y nvarchar(100) = TRIM( ',' FROM REPLACE( @x, '0', ',0' ) )
```

or:

```
DECLARE @y nvarchar(100) = ''

DECLARE @idx int = CHARINDEX( '0', @x )
WHILE @idx > 0
BEGIN;

    SET @y = @y + ',' + SUBSTRING( @x, @idx, 2 )

    SET @idx =  CHARINDEX( '0', @x, @idx + 1 )

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution a litle abstract that uses the newest function from sql server 2017.

```
DECLARE @x NVARCHAR(MAX) = '01020304'

DECLARE @seperator NVARCHAR(MAX) = '0'

SELECT STRING_AGG(@seperator+value,',')
FROM string_split(@x, @seperator) 
WHERE value <> ''
```

Basiclly it uses the seperator and then adds it to the values. using string agg to create your string

Comment: From [`String_Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks): "The output rows might be in any order. The order is _not_ guaranteed to match the order of the substrings in the input string."